# Ionic selectable component, selected value not showing in console log

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, viewchild

I'm working on an app that uses ionic-selectable for a dropdown list and when an item is selected the fields below the selector would auto populate the items' values. But I'm stuck even before tying to populate the fields. When I try to console log the values of the selected item on the event change, nothing comes up in the console, not even an error.

html:

```html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size-lg="6" md="3">
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Vehicle Search</ion-label>
    <ionic-selectable
      #selectComponent
      [(ngModel)]="selected"
      [items]="vehicles"
      itemValueField="id"
      itemTextField="name"
      [canSearch]="true"
      searchFailText= "Vehicle not found">
  </ionic-selectable>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

ts code:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {  IonicSelectableComponent } from 'ionic-selectable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-work-order',
  templateUrl: './work-order.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./work-order.page.scss'],
})

export class WorkOrderPage {
  vehicles = [
      { id:1,
        name: 'Chevy Truck',
        unitNumber: 123 },
      { id:2,
        name: 'Ford Truck',
        unitNumber: 456 },
      { id: 3,
        name: 'Dodge Truck',
        unitNumber: 789 }
    ];
    @ViewChild('selectComponent') selectComponent: IonicSelectableComponent;
    selected = [];

    vehicleChanged(event: {
      component: IonicSelectableComponent,
      value: any

      })
      {console.log(event.unitNumber);}


}
```

module.ts

```html
import { IonicSelectableModule } from 'ionic-selectable';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WorkOrderPage } from './work-order.page';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: WorkOrderPage
      }

    ]),
    IonicSelectableModule
  ],
  declarations: [WorkOrderPage]
})
export class WorkOrderPageModule {}
```

I've looked through questions but haven't found what is wrong with how it is written.  I'm very new to coding so I apologize if the etiquette of my question is incorrect. Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You should let `ionic-selectable` emit change event -> `(onChange)="vehicleChanged($event)"` which you are not doing at present ;)

Comment: Solved! Thank you Mr.Tadisetti! I've been looking at this for days